# Gradle print path of used jars in gradle init script

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I need to print the path of the jar files used by gradle.

Currently if I include the following lines in my top folder gradle project I am able to get the correct information:

```
allprojects {
    task printDependencies << {task -> println "Subproject -> $task.project.name" }
}

subprojects {
    printDependencies {
        afterEvaluate { Project project ->
            if (configurations.find { it.name == 'compile' }) {
                doLast {
                    println "$project.configurations.compile.asPath\n"
                }}}}}
```

Now I wanted to include this behavior into a init script as to avoid copying this code to all my build.gradle files.

The problem is I cannot get it to work at ${HOME}/.gradle/somename.gradle. The first error that pops up is:

```
Could not find method subprojects() for arguments
```

Is there any way to put this behaviour in a gradle init file?

Comment: Instead of using `project.afterEvaluate`, that logic can go inside `doLast`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle build scripts delegate to an instance of the [Project](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html) class (see [chapter 13 Gradle User guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html)), so that is where the `subprojects` method comes from.

However init scripts delegate to an instance of [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html) (see [60.3 Gradle User guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#N16A17)), which does not have a `subprojects` method.

It does have a `rootProject` method,so you probaby want something like

```
   projectsEvaluated {
     rootProject.subprojects {
         ...
     }
   }
```

Comment: It does not work. The error message is:
> The root project is not yet available for build.

Comment: Take a look at the api for the Gradle class that I linked to. I can see a number of approaches that you could try using them. I have updated the example in my answer to use one such approach.